# Splice function working inversely, not working properly

Tags: javascript

I was building an angular app.
I needed a array to remove an element from particular index.
i just used splice method. But it doesn't removes the element from the index. It removes entire element apart from the index which i have provided. You can check this in your chrome console itself.

I don't know what's the exact reason but when i have checked in jsfiddle and w3schools, It was working properly.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(3,1);
["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]
```

it should now return like above array

but instead it is returning this

```
[mango]
```

**It is weird but pls check from your console and comment**

Comment: please add the whole array and what you like to get.

Comment: `splice()` modifies the array in place, and returns the removed elements.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yeah that's the answer i was looking for. thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how `.splice()` works, it does not return the changed array, but the added/removed elements, it will modify the original array!

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
// returns the REMOVED element, e.g. 'Mango'
console.log(fruits.splice(3,1));
// but the actual array $fruits, has changed to
// ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]
console.log(fruits)
```